# Plugin to Add Multiple Parent Categories for Child Category Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add multiple parent categories for a child category.. Suggest me if there is any plugin..

The actual flow is

State As Parent Category
Consistency & Political Parties are sub categories of state
MLA is sub category of both Consistency & Party

Comment: Can you explain little bit clear and what you are tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. You won't find a plugin because you can't have multiple parent categories.

You should keep an open mind to solutions before painting yourself into a corner pursuing something like this. My suggestion would be to look into custom taxonomies.

Comment: Custom taxonomies also present one to many relation as posts to parent posts and categories to category parents.

Answer (score 0):

Custom taxonomies are not a solution here as they use the same database structure and constraints. Multiple parents would require a change in db constraints